# Cannot find genesis block in mongodb

Tags: nodeos, blocks, history, plugin

I am trying running nodeos with Mongo Db Plugin. Following is my nodeos:

```
nodeos \
--signature-provider Pubkey=KEY:PrivKey\
--plugin eosio::producer_plugin \
--plugin eosio::producer_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::chain_plugin \
--plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::http_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_plugin \
--plugin eosio::mongo_db_plugin \
--abi-serializer-max-time-ms=5000 \
--mongodb-uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/EOS \
--mongodb-wipe --hard-replay-blockchain \
--data-dir $DATADIR"/data" \
--blocks-dir $DATADIR"/blocks" \
--config-dir $DATADIR"/config" \
--producer-name eosio \
--http-server-address 127.0.0.1:8888 \
--p2p-listen-endpoint 127.0.0.1:9010 \
--access-control-allow-origin='*' \
--contracts-console \
--http-validate-host=false \
--verbose-http-errors \
--enable-stale-production \
--p2p-peer-address localhost:9011 \
--p2p-peer-address localhost:9012 \
--p2p-peer-address localhost:9013 \
>> $DATADIR"/nodeos.log" 2>&1 & \
echo $! > $DATADIR"/eosd.pid"
```

nodeos data is getting save in mongodb. But I cannot find block number one. I tried to get using:

> db.blocks.find({"block_num":1}).pretty()

It returned nothing. Using `cleos get block 1` I am getting the result. Can anybody please tell me why this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the design of eosio. You can find the related information from here.

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/7690

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer!